How to use gdal3.js for rasterization
I am trying to use gdal3.js to rasterize GeoJSON to GeoTIFF format in a vanilla JS web app but it is throwing the following error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t.arrayBuffer is not a function
    at gdal3.js:1:178894

I am new to using this package. I am importing the package via CDN as follows:
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gdal3.js@2.8.1/dist/package/gdal3.js"
    integrity="sha384-yW4c2Jx7lsREjJg58+ZI5U6gAso2bRAPw3LdzPWm7z8+rMJ24R7AS+EFyXDPxgYM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Example usage is as follows:
initGdalJs({ path: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gdal3.js@2.8.1/dist/package', useWorker: false }).then(async (Gdal) => {
      const geojson = {
          "type": "FeatureCollection",
          "features": [
              {
                  "type": "Feature",
                  "geometry": {
                      "type": "Polygon",
                      "coordinates": [
                          [
                              [-101.744384765625, 39.32155002466662],
                              [-101.5521240234375, 39.330048552942415],
                              [-101.40380859375, 39.330048552942415],
                              [-101.33239746093749, 39.364032338047984],
                              [-101.041259765625, 39.36827914916011],
                              [-100.975341796875, 39.30454987014581],
                              [-101.0399169921875, 39.24501680713314],
                              [-101.243896484375, 39.16414104768742],
                              [-101.455078125, 39.11301365149975],
                              [-101.7376708984375, 39.28474226883173],
                              [-101.744384765625, 39.32155002466662]
                          ]
                      ]
                  }
              }
          ]
      };
  
      const options = {
          format: 'GTiff',
          outputType: Gdal.GDT_Byte,
          width: 256,
          height: 256
      };
  
      Gdal.gdal_rasterize(geojson, options).then((raster) => {
          console.log('Rasterized GeoJSON:', raster);
      }).catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error rasterizing GeoJSON:', error);
      });
  });

